# How to correlate several binary (binominal) variables with each other?

Tags: correlation, binary-data, association-measure

I have a dataset that describes the answers of students to 7 questions (correct/wrong). So:

|  | Question1 | Question2 | ... | Question7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| student#1 | correct | correct |  | wrong |
| student#2 | wrong | correct |  | correct |
| student#3 | correct | correct |  | correct |
| ... | ... | ... |  | ... |

I want to correlate each question with each other to see patterns, e.g., when Q1 was answered correct also Q7 tends to be answered correct.

What method can I use? Tetrachoric correlation? Point-Biserial Correlation? Pearson?

I am unsure which method is the most appropriate to compare several binary (binomial) variables?

Comment: Your sense of "correlate strongly" is strange.  The only reasons why "b tends to be 1" is that most values of b are 1!  That has little or nothing to do with the value of a: that's what the small magnitude of $\phi$ is telling you. What kind of comparison among these variables do you really want to perform?

Comment: oh yes, thank you very much! I removed this wrong illustration example. I want to identify patterns, e.g. persons who answered Q6 correct also tend to answer Q7 correct.

Comment: Are you interested in drawing conclusions only about those specific students who answered these specific questions at this specific time, and nothing more? Or do you want to draw some more general conclusions? (In other words: are these students a sample, or a population?)

Comment: It will probably help to highlight if you are looking to draw conclusions about item-level relationships, subject-level relationships related to the items, constructing factors based on subsets of the test, or some other idea you are trying to illuminate. My best guess is that you believe certain items are related because of some overarching construct, which hints to a degree that a latent variable is at play.

Comment: yes, I aim to find some overarching construct. In case I identify some associations between questions I may look further by analyzing additional properties of the students. These students are just a sample and I want to be able to conclude the entire population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of the interrater agreement test based on Cohen's kappa statistic would help identify if a pair of questions were answered the same (both responses correct or both responses wrong). An example two by two table for Q1 and Q2 for n=50 responses for both questions would look as follows:

[image]

The focus is on the accumulation of counts on the diagonal of the 2x2 table, which indicate agreement between both responses across the two questions considered.

Comment: The data presented above isn't in count form, they are binaries. I don't see how a chi-square test is appropriate here given OP asked about associations between binary item scores. If your idea was to sum the totals of the questions (as above), a chi-square test still doesn't get at the core of the issue because it is not measuring magnitude...it just says we can reject the null.

Comment: I already addressed that in the second sentence (perhaps with poor wording), where sum counts of "wrong" and "right" answers are included into a contingency table like yours for a chi-square test. I must reiterate that this only tests the null hypothesis ("there is no difference between the cell counts"), which is not the same as "what is the magnitude of association between Question 1 and 2" or even "what is the magnitude of a given cluster of questions with each other?"

Comment: See modified answer - the appropriate test that could be used is interrator agreement.

Comment: thank you. When I try Cohen Kappa in R on your example above I get 0.8305 (95% conf. level). When I use Pearson correlation I get 0.834. So both methods show an association. 

As a corrplot can easily be drawn in R (using Paerson) for all questions, I think I will stick to using Pearson r.